# The following error occurred: Application-defined or object-defined error 1004 VBAProject

Tags: excel, vba, macos

```
Function copyHeader(inputrange As String, inputsheet As String, outputcell As String, outputsheet As String)
    Sheets(inputsheet).Range(inputrange).Copy Destination:=Sheets(outputsheet).Range(outputcell)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Cells(1, 1).Value = 4  'probably better to make this dynamic
End Function

Function copyDetail(inputrange As String, inputsheet As String, outputcell As String, outputsheet As String)
    Sheets(inputsheet).Range(inputrange).Copy Destination:=Sheets(outputsheet).Range(outputcell)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Cells(1, 1).Value = 4  'probably better to make this dynamic
End Function

Function createTab(tabname As String)
    Worksheets.Add.Name = tabname
End Function

Function shtExists(shtname As String) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Set sht = Sheets(shtname)
    shtExists = True
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        shtExists = False
    End If
End Function

Public Function lastCell(Col As String)
    With ActiveSheet
        lastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Sub AddData()
    Dim teamname As String
    Dim countery As Integer
    Dim teamdata As String
    Dim matchcounter As String
    Dim resp As Boolean
    Dim maxCounter As Integer

    counter = 4
    maxCounter = lastCell("B")

    On Error GoTo eh
    For counter = 4 To maxCounter
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry").Select
        teamdata = "C" & counter & ":" & "N" & counter
        teamname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataEntry").Range("B" & counter).Value

    resp = shtExists(teamname)

    If resp = False Then
        createTab (teamname)

        copyHeader "C1:M3", "DataEntry", "B1", teamname
        matchcounter = CStr(Sheets(teamname).Range("A1").Value)
        copyDetail teamdata, "DataEntry", "B" & matchcounter, teamname

    ElseIf resp = True Then
        copyDetail teamdata, "DataEntry", "B" & matchcounter, teamname
    End If
    Next counter

Worksheets("DataEntry").Activate
Done:
    Exit Sub
eh:
    MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & Err.Description & " " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Source
End Sub
```

So When I try and Run this as you saw from the title I get an Application-defined or object-defined error: 1004. I a, trying to make it iterate through cells B4 to B9 and at each one and if there is no sheet with the name in that cell it creates it and pastes the headers that are on the data entry page (C1:M3) and the data on that row from C to I onto the newly created sheet. If it does exist it looks at A1 of the sheet with that name and pastes the data into column B and the row that A1 specifies. And it does this for B4:B9 on each cell. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You should use the string in range with statement, `teamdata = Range(stringcombine).Value` OR you have to make teamdata as range to preserve multiple values from Range object.

Comment: @MukulVarshney what you suggested gave me the same error. could you give me an example of the second one though?

Comment: could we move to vba lounge and then post final results if any on here?

Comment: What''s in A1 when you run this code? Can't see as it's behind a button in your picture.

Comment: There is nothing in column A at all

Comment: Then how do you expect `matchcounter = Cells(1, 1).Value` to work?

Comment: @Rory that is going to be on the new sheet it creates not the dataentry sheet

Comment: But that line is before you create any new sheets.

Comment: but when i refer to the variable wont it just look it up in the current sheet? or does it take a value store it in memory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138381/discussion-between-theman26-and-rory).

Answer (score 2):

> `Dim teamdata As String`
>
> `stringcombine = "C" & countery & ":" & "M" & countery`
>
> `teamdata = Range(stringcombine)`

Here you are assigning an array (of 11 entries) to a string, hence the *type mismatch*.

Upon reading your code, what you meant to do was

```
teamdata = Range(stringcombine).Address
```

though it wasn't necessary to create an additional variable `teamdata` for the address, you already had it in `stringcombine`.

Comment: So i tried it and it gave me "Compile error:
Method or data member not found"
@A.S.H.

Comment: one second @.A.S.H.

Comment: it is on the line that you said to change

Comment: Well I'm really speechless, unable to understand that. Only thing I can say, urgently set `Option explicit` and qualify your ranges.

Comment: Ok will do A.S.H.

Comment: Now I tried option explicit and it gives me error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error and points to the third line of my program which has the really long copypaste part of it:
Sheets(inputsheet).Range(inputrange).Copy Destination:=Sheets(outputsheet).Range(outputcell)

Comment: You must have a bad parameter `outputcell`.  it is set to `"B" & matchcounter` with `matchcounter As String = Cells(1, 1).Value `, that must be empty so you get `outputcell = "B"`, that's not a valid cell address.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the copypaste function, it appears that inputRange parameter should have a string value like "C3:M3". You pass teamdata to copypaste as the inputrange parameter, so are you expecting teamdata to have a value like "C3:M3"? If so, then your line

```
teamdata = Range(stringcombine)
```

could be

```
teamdata = stringcombine
```

What the current line attempts to do is take the values from the range of cells and assign them to a string variable -- which it isn't designed to do. If stringcombine were something like "M3" it would work ok. One cell value to one string.

Comment: do you guys want me to send a picture of what my file looks like so you can see better?

Comment: Your answer got the furthest @RichHolton but now it gives me Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error

it highlights the line that you said to change. thanks for responding so quickly!

Comment: Things are really making no sense. Sometimes VBA seems to get fatally confused. You might try forcing a project reset (see below) then exiting Excel completely, then restarting and trying again.
To force the reset, add an Enum at the top of the vba file. Something like
Enum X
One
Two
Three
End Enum

You can delete this after you restart Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Error 13 generally means you're trying to assign a value to a variable that can't accept that data type, or you're trying to pass the wrong data type as an argument to a sub or function.

If I've understood your requirements, this should be able to replace your existing code:

```
Sub AddData_ReWrite()
    Dim teamName        As String
    Dim i               As Integer
    Dim matchCounter    As String
    Dim dataEntry       As Excel.Worksheet

    matchCounter = Range("A1").Value
    Set dataEntry = Sheets("DataEntry")

    For i = 4 To 9
        teamName = Sheets("DataEntry").Range("B" & i).Value
        CreateSheetIfNotExists teamName
        Sheets(teamName).Range("B" & matchCounter & ":N" & matchCounter).Value = dataEntry.Range("C" & i & ":M" & i).Value
    Next

    dataEntry.Activate

End Sub

Sub CreateSheetIfNotExists(ByVal sheetName As String)
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

        Set sht = Sheets(sheetName)

ErrHandler:
    If (Err.Number) Then
        If Err.Number = 9 Then
            With Worksheets.Add
                .Name = sheetName
                .Range("B1:N3").Value = Sheets("DataEntry").Range("C1:M3").Value
                .Range("A1").Value = 2
            End With
        Else
            '// What if it isn't error 9?
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ":" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
        End If
    End If

    '// clear errors and reset error handler
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I've tidied it up a bit to improve the readability and added extra error handling in your other sub routine.

Comment: So as you probably saw i have a button on the Data Entry sheet. So which sub would i assign the button to?

Comment: I'm guessing it was originally assigned to `AddData()` in which case assign it to `AddData_ReWrite()`

Comment: Is it supposed to return Error 0?

Comment: so it doesnt return an error but... it creates a mess

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYo0P.png